# Is there a simple way to rewrite the PHP code attached (using arrays as a lookup table perhaps)?

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement, range, lookup-tables

```
switch ($hiBid) {
case ($hiBid > 0 && $hiBid <= 1):
    $minIncrement = .01;
    break;
case ($hiBid > 1 && $hiBid <= 5):
    $minIncrement = .25;
    break;
case ($hiBid > 5 && $hiBid <= 25):
    $minIncrement = 1;
    break;
case ($hiBid > 25 && $hiBid <= 100):
    $minIncrement = 5;
    break;    
case ($hiBid > 100 && $hiBid <= 500):
    $minIncrement = 10;
    break;
case ($hiBid > 500 && $hiBid <= 1000):
    $minIncrement = 25;
    break;
}
```

Looking for way to simplify this code more like a database lookup table, primarily to allow many more range comparisons that will be easier to read like a spreadsheet, where they will be initially defined.

Comment: This might be better suited to the Code Review stackexchange site

Comment: Use an array whose keys are the upper limits of each range and values are the increments, in descending order. Loop through the array until `$hibid` is less than the key, then assign the increment and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you find yourself writing repetitive code like this you can probably re-envision it as a loop and an array.

```php
function getIncrement($bid, $tholds, $min=0) {
    $max = max(array_keys($tholds));
    if( $bid <= $min || $bid > $max ) {
        throw new \Exception("Bid outside threshold range");
    }
    
    $prev = $min;
    foreach( $tholds as $thold => $increment ) {
        if( $bid > $prev && $bid <= $thold ) {
            return $increment;
        }
        $prev = $thold;
    }
}

$tholds = [
       1 =>  0.01,
       5 =>  0.25,
      25 =>  1.00,
     100 =>  5.00,
     500 => 10.00,
    1000 => 25.00
];

var_dump(getIncrement(256, $tholds));
```

Ouput:

```
float(10)
```

Comment: Ty. Was aware of the looping method. Was wondering if there was a faster way to do it, perhaps some PHP array range-compare methods that I did not know about...

Comment: No. There's no builtin for this. A person _could_ rewrite this using a more efficient lookup and/or data structure, but unless you're planning to have several _thousand_ threshold values it would take more time to write the code than you would ever save in CPU cycles.

Comment: What are the advantages to refactoring code like this when it's slightly longer, harder to understand, and likely slower?

Comment: @HashimAziz Because it answers the question that was asked. Because you can change the thresholds without rewriting swaths of boilerplate code. Because it's not really that hard to read. Because it has bounds checking and error reporting. Because the amount that this _might_ be slower would be difficult to measure even if you looped it a billion times.